# Reduce duplication of the code in the android Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm really struggling with the Firestore to reduce the duplication of the code. Recently I have asked the question with the different topic but the little bit similar problem. Here I'm asking the question that how I can reduce the duplication of the code in android for Firestore?

Suppose I have to get the `city` document by the `city` name then I have to write each time this code.

```
db.collection("cities")
    .whereEqualTo("name", name)
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot query) {
            query.getDocuments().get(0).getReference(); 
           // make custom call back here to get the value of this 
           // outside of here but that is not enough to reduce 
           // duplication of code.
        }
    });
```

Suppose I have to get the 10 documents and that could be about hundred times in application then `100*10 = 1000` time duplication the similar code, really? 
I didn't found any solution of this problem. I don't know why there is not enough information about this? is there any code patters for Firestore? that could help me to reduce my effort for rewriting code?

Don't know why this is forcing me to hate the Firestore in coding duplication context. -_-

@Downvoter, if you think this is stupid question then please elaborate why? do you know the answer? or is there any similar question with answer?

Comment: "Suppose I have to get the 10 documents", what does it mean? You want to get 10 different city documents by their corresponding city name? Or you want to get in one call 10 city names ?

Comment: @AlexMamo I want to get 10 different city documents by their corresponding name.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the duplication a little bit by defining this method:

```
void addCityListener(String name, OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot> listener){
    db.collection("cities")
      .whereEqualTo("name", name)
      .get()
      .addOnSuccessListener(listener);
}
```

then, you call the method like this:

```
addCityListener(name, new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>(){
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot query){
        // do something with the query
    }
});
```

and if you're using Java 8 in your project, you can reduce the code even further using a lambda:

```
addCityListener(name, (QuerySnapshot query)->{
    // do something with the query
});
```